# char * string to hex uint8_t value in order to modify a .hex file

Tags: c, string, file, hex

I have a .hex file and I want to modify some concrete positions of that file with other hex values.

I have stored the data I want to use to modify the file in 
`uint8_t *linedata[2];`

Concretely in `linedata[1]`. If I use:

```
printf("%s\n", linedata[1]);
```

Output:

> 11f3efcc2898ce4c3a0287acb774d90b

I get the string I want, but I need it in format `00` to `FF`, so I use a `uint8_t *value` for such purpose like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    sscanf(linedata[1] + (j * 2),"%02x", &value[j]);

for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    printf("%02x\n", (unsigned int)value[j]);
```

But now the result is wrong in the first two prints:

> 00 00 ef cc 28 98 ce 4c 3a 02 87 ac b7 74 d9 0b

Besides I can't modify well the hex file, I try to use `fseek` to set the pointer in the position I want to write but, how can I know the memory position where I should write? Because it doesn't seem to match with the character count, may be multiply each character count by the sizeof an hex in memory?

I'm going to post all the code here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

const int NUMBER = 2;

nt main(int argc, unsigned char * argv[])
{
    int j=0;
    uint8_t *linedata[2];
    uint8_t *arraykey=malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*16);
    //uint8_t *arraykey=linedata[1];
    uint8_t *pos;
    uint8_t *value;
    unsigned char *valor;
    size_t i,n;
    value = malloc(sizeof(value));

    char ch;
    int check;
    char *hexsource="ble_app_beacon.hex";
    char *hextarget;
    char *hextag=".hex";
    int cont=1;
    int stringindex=0;
    uint8_t dataarray[16];
    int count=0;
    int w=0;

    uint8_t prueba[16]={0x52,0x87,0x1D,0x6B,0x9D,0x60,0x00,0x46,0xD7,0x20,0xD4,0x73,0x90,0xEE,0x42,0xBC};

    FILE *ptr_file, *source, *target;;

    char buf[40];

    ptr_file =fopen("comercekeyfile","r");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;

    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf), ptr_file)!=NULL)
    {
        char *dbuff=strdup(buf);
        linedata[n]=strtok(dbuff, ":");
        n++;
        linedata[n]=strtok(NULL,":");

        printf("%s\n",linedata[0]); //linedata[0] is the commerce id
        printf("%s\n", linedata[1]); //linedata[1] is the commerce KEY

        //n = strlen(linedata[1]) / 2;
        n=16;
        source = fopen (hexsource, "r");

        if( source == NULL )
        {
            printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //IT'S FAILING HERE FOR SURE
        hextarget=strcat(linedata[0],hextag);
        target=fopen (hextarget, "w");

        if( target == NULL )
        {
            fclose(source);
            printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while( ( ch = fgetc(source) ) != EOF )
        {
            fputc(ch, target);
            cont++;
        }
        fclose(target);
        target=fopen (hextarget, "r+");
        fseek ( target , 11505 , SEEK_SET );

        if (value == NULL) 
        {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("%s\n",linedata[1]);

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            sscanf(linedata[1] + (sizeof(uint8_t))*(j * 2),"%02x", &value[j]);

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%02x\n", (unsigned int)value[j]);

        free(value);
        /*
        check=mkdir(linedata[0],0777);

        if(!check)
            printf("Directory created\n");
        else
            printf("Unable to create Directory\n");
         */

        free(dbuff);
        n=0;
        printf("File copied successfully.\n");
        cont=1;
        stringindex=0;

        fclose(source);
        fclose(target);

    }
    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea?

I think the fail must be when I use `hextarget=strcat(linedata[0],hextag);`
May be trying to allocate the memory I could fix it, but I'm not sure.

I expect to get the same data printed using `linedata[1]` but in value, because I need `00-FF` format in order to store the hex key I get from a file in a concrete memory position.
For example I have this .hex file:

> :1097B00005DA00214042914111A60A4608E00099CD
>   :1097C00009688B0701D50FA602E0490701D50EA64F
>   :1097D00001251146009F0024243704E000F0E1F940
>   :1097E00030323A55641C02460A43F7D12B463246C2
>   :1097F0002146009800F012FAFEBD000000000000B3

And I need to modify this and get:

> :1097B00005DA00214042914111A60A4608E00099CD
>   :1097C00009688B0701D50FA602E0490701D50EA64F
>   :1097D00001251146009F0024243704E000F0E1F940
>   :1097E00030323A55641C02460A43F7D12B463246C2
>   :1097F00021**11f3efcc2898ce4c3a0287acb774d90b**

Thanks you very much.

Comment: And what output do you expect ? How are `value` and `linedata` declared ?

Comment: ... and what's the value of `n` ? Post more code.

Comment: Here is described the Intel hex file format, if that is what you mean: http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1584/

Comment: The code you posted can't be the code you used because `printf("%02x\n", (unsigned int)value[j]);` does not output the space you show between each value, and because when I tried it, the first two values are correct. But I would have declared `value` as `unsigned int` not `unsigned char`.

Comment: With this code I get the results I put. I think I'm writing in a memory address I shouldn't and I invade the memory didicated to linedata[1] with the value stored in line data[0] when I concatenate the .hex to the name of the file I want to create.

Comment: Minor notes: 1) `'0'` in `sscanf(linedata[1] + (j * 2),"%02x"` not needed.  2) `char ch;` --> `int ch;`

Comment: `sscanf(linedata[1] + (j * 2),"%02x", &value[j]);` --> `#include <inttypes.h> .... sscanf(linedata[1] + (j * 2),"%2" SCNx8 , &value[j]);`

Answer (score 1):

What is this?

```
uint8_t *value;
...
value = malloc(sizeof(value));
```

This allocates memory for a single pointer. Later you are indexing `value[15]` with the statements

```
n=16;
...
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    printf("%02x\n", (unsigned int)value[j]);
```

But the code is such a mess it's hard to see if you are doing anything right. For example you have used `n` for two different purposes and finally reset it to 0 at the end of your `while` loop. As a static variable it will be initialised to 0, but in a loop you should really set it before use, not after.

Comment: `n` is not a static variable, it's a *local* variable and so it will *not* automatically be initialised with 0. (Unless the compiler does so. Some do, most don't, and absolutely no-one should *rely* on this.)

Comment: Good point @Jongware. In that case `linedata[n]=strtok(dbuff, ":");` is using an uninitialised `n`

Comment: I have modified many times and in different ways the code, that's why it is a bit messy. I'll try initializing everything well but when I print linedata[1] I get the right string so, maybe I'm lucky but it isn't failing there. If I use printf with linedata[1] after the strcat is when the value changes and fails. Edited: Initializing all the values the result is the same

Comment: Lucky? Programming isn't about luck. Perhaps it's time for a re-write. It hurts to admit it, but in the long run, it's usually better.

Comment: I know porgramming is not about luck it was only an expression :(. So I'll try to rewrite... I don't understand the negative votes when I'm only asking for help, I feel as if I was being evaluated more than advised... But thanks anyway and sorry for not being so good programmer, I only want to improve and to get the result I want. Regards and sorry again for waste your time :/